# Insert data in different tables from one form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have one form and I want to insert data from that form in multiple tables in symfony2.

I have 5 tables (entities) in total, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
    $company_var = new Company();
    $adresses_var = new Adresses();

    $contacts_var = new Contacts();
    $licenses_var = new Licenses();
    $owners_var = new Owners();

$form = $this->createForm(new NewformController(), $company_var);
$form = $this->createForm(new NewformController(), $adresses_var);
$form = $this->createForm(new NewformController(), $contacts_var);
$form = $this->createForm(new NewformController(), $licenses_var);
$form = $this->createForm(new NewformController(), $owners_var);
```

and then persist them into database like this:

```
$em->persist($company_var);
                $em->persist($adresses_var);
                $em->persist($contacts_var);
                $em->persist($licenses_var);
                $em->persist($owners_var);
                $em->flush();
```

I heard of embedded forms but i don't think that works for me. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are all this variables related? If not, then you should have 1 form per entity, you are just overriding the `$form` variable.

Comment: they are not related. I can't use 1 form for every entity, all data must be submitted in all tables with 1 click.

Comment: Then create a Custom form type and embed all your forms. when the form is submitted then grab each field and persist them.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I have posted below what i tried and didn't work.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not hard but you really need to spend sometime on the basics before tackling this.  Otherwise, you won't understand what is going on and even if you get it to work, it will be very fragile and difficult for you to maintain.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html